# How to create Gson object with TypeAdapterFactory to match my POKO model?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I managed to get retrofit working with the following POKO:

```
data class GifSerialList(var data: List<GifSerial>)
data class GifSerial(var id: String,
                 var title: String,
                 @SerializedName("import_datetime") var importDatetime: String,
                 var user: User?,
                 var images: Image)
data class User(@SerializedName("display_name") var userDisplayName: String)
data class Image(@SerializedName("fixed_height") var fixedHeight: Size)
data class Size(var url: String)
```

Matching following json:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "oefi3of93jf2f9",
        ...
        "import_datetime": "2014-03-29 13:55:35",
        ...
        "user": {
            ...
            "display_name": "User Display Name",
        },
        "images": {
            ...             
            "fixed_height": {
                "url": "https://giflink.gif",
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        "title": "GIF Title",
        ...
    },
    {
```

With the following retrofit request:

```
@GET("trending")
fun getTrending(@Query("api_key") apiKey: String): Call<GifSerialList>
```

I figured to make it right & avoid GifSerialList monstrosity I should be using TypeAdapterFactory to create json matching my original POKO:

```
data class Gif(var id: String,
           var title: String,
           @SerializedName("display_name") var authorDisplayName: String?,
           @SerializedName("import_datetime") var importDateTime: String,
           var url: String) : Parcelable
```

Questions:

Is TypeAdapterFactory - read(input: JsonReader) a right approach here?

Which retrofit request with TypeAdapterFactory should I be using in my case?

```
fun getTrending(@Query("api_key") apiKey: String): Call<List<Gif>>
fun getTrending(@Query("api_key") apiKey: String): Call<Gif>
fun getTrending(@Query("api_key") apiKey: String): Call<GifSerialList>
```

Any advice on putting my json read() function content together?
So far I get typical BEGIN_ARRAY or BEGIN_OBJECT exceptions whatever I try.
My incomplete TypeAdapterFactory read() function below:

```
override fun read(input: JsonReader): T {
                var jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(input)
                var jsonObject = jsonElement.asJsonObject
                val jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("data")
                for (item in jsonArray) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "item: $item")
                    jsonObject = item.asJsonObject
                }
                jsonElement = jsonObject
                return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement)
            }
```

How do I pick required json Gif POKO elements and return them together? Do I need to create a List of json elements here and then return?

Comment: You can use GSON to parse `json` file and receive Kotlin object (or list of them): https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Have you fixed that problem?

Comment: Nope. Not even sure if I should be creating a json tree or json object values in the read() method. In retrofit request I ask for a List<Gif>, so should I be building a json tree in write() method or Gif object? How I understand json tree: [{id, import_datetime, display_name, url, title}, ... ]. Is it what delegate.fromJsonTree is expecting? If so, what methods should I be using to put it together?